# Windows Server 2008: How to add a network printer to all users in Active Directory

Tags: windows, networking, printer

We have an office with about 10 members and 4 printers. All of the printers are network printers with their own IP adress. All the users are part of the smae group in Active Diretory. The AD is running on a Windows Server 2008 (not R2). All the client machines are part of the same domain.

At the moment I go to every PC and install the printer drivers manually. Which options do i have to do this on the central server and how?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has written a comprehensive Step-by-step guide to setting up print services in a domain:
[Technet: Print Management Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753109(v=ws.10).aspx)

In short:

- Install the Print Services Role on the server you intend to use as a print server
- Install the Print Management Feature component on any machine you'd like to manage print service from
- Add your network printers to the print servers
- Configure printer mappings using Group Policy preferences
- Have fun printing away!

The Print Services role can coexist with AD DS, no problem, but I strongly suggest that you dedicate another server to network application services like Print, File and DHCP Services etc. and keep the Domain Controller "clean" of other roles.

Comment: Dont forget to install the 'Group Policy Preferences Client Side Extensions' on any XP or Vista machines if you have them.